# Appending a Dictionary using a for loop. Combining two existing CSV into a new one

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files that contain information.  I need to combine parts of each CSV into a new one.

The CSV are
CSV_A headers= "Header_1, Header_3, Header_5".
CSV_A rows....
CSV_B = "Header_2, Header_4, Header_3".
CSV_B rows...

The common header is Header_3.

I need to create a new CSV that contains "Header_1, Header_4." joined together where Header_3 is the same for the respective row in each CSV.  If this were an SQL Database this could be accomplished sort of with a "Join".  I want to do this here but I don't think the join function exists for python.

The Python code I am working on to accomplish this is this:

```
#Create an empty list to be used as rows in a dictionary.
dictionary_rows = []

#open CSV_A, iterate through it with a for loop, appending the header_1 and #header_3 to the dictionary_rows list.
with open('CSV_A.csv') as file_object:
    reader_object = csv.DictReader(file_object)
    for row in reader_object:
        list = [row['Header_1'], row['Header_3']]
        dictionary_rows.append(list)

#iterate through the dictionary_rows list,with each row open CSV_B, iterate #through it finding a match on Header_3, where a match is found, append #dictionary_rows on the matching line.
e = 0
for row in dictionary_rows:          
    with open('CSV_B.csv') as file_object:
        reader_object = csv.DictReader(file_object)
        for i in reader_object:
            if i['Header_3'] in row[1]:
                variable = dictionary_rows[e]
                variable.append(i[1])
                e += 1
                print(f"This is the occupancy id {i['Occupancy ID']}")
                break
            else:
                pass
```

Trying the listed code I expected to  append the dictionary_rows list with the corresponding values from the matching CSV rows.  I researched "Merging" CSV's but this didn't seem to solve the problem I needed solved.  I have spent some time researching, even asking chat-gpt and was unable to figure this one out.  I think I am not asking the correct questions and I am stuck.

Comment: Your code doesn't even do any writing... are you trying to simply manipulate the data in memory or are you trying to edit one of the csv files?

Comment: Good observation.  Currently, this is only in memory.  It will write to a new CSV once complete but I am still writing it and hit a roadblock before I got to the write CSV part.  I have a few more steps to get to that part yet.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you’re looking for is a dictionary, which you can key on a particular value (in this case the Header_3 column) to make it easy to look up or aggregate data.

```
# Get rows from A keyed on H3.
with open('CSV_A.csv') as f:
    rows = {
        row['Header_3']: row
        for row in csv.DictReader(f)
    }

# Update those rows from B.
with open('CSV_B.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        rows[row['Header_3']].update(row)

# Write H1 and H4 to C.
with open('CSV_C.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv.DictWriter(
        f,
        ['Header_1', 'Header_4'],
        extrasaction='ignore'
    ).writerows(rows.values())
```

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to do exactly what I need.  I still need to learn more about some python basics.  Reading this, "rows{row['Header_3']].update(row)", is very confusing and will take some time for me to digest.

Comment: Read nested expressions from the inside out.  In that line, `row` is a row of CSV_B, right?  So `row['Header_3']` is the value in column 3 from that B row.  `rows` is the dict we built from CSV_A, and because it’s keyed on that column 3 value, we can access the matching A row by providing that value as a key, hence `rows[row['Header_3']]`.  Since that A row is a dict, we can call `.update(row)` on it to combine it with our B row.